# problem handling upload file django

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to do a feature that would allow the user to upload a file. That file would have information to insert into the database, that's why in the function I'm saving data. Not sure if it's the best option.

What I've done so far:

forms.py:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views:

```
def last_step(request, word):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            msg = handle_uploaded_file(word, request.FILES['file'])
            return render_to_response('final_insert.html', {'msg': msg})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', 
                               {
                                'word': word,
                                'form': form })
```

template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url upload_done 'clinical' %}" method="post">
<div>
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %} 
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
</form>
```

function:

```
def handle_uploaded_file(word, f):
    msg = "first stop" 
    data = []
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        data.append(chunk)
    msg = "after chunk"    

    if word == 'clinical':
        pat = Patient.objects.values_list('patient', flat=True)
        for i in data:
            if i[0] not in pat:
                b2 = Patient(patient=i[0])
                b2.save()
                msg = "number was inserted"
            else:
                msg = "something"

    return msg
```

The problem is when I hit "save" in the template, it redirects well to another template, but I don't see any message, like I suppose to see (final_insert.html shows {{ msg }})

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?
Any help is welcome!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the code snippet of final_insert.html?

Comment: the final_insert.html is just the variable msg. I'm uploading the file and with the function handle_uploaded_file I would like to insert the data from the file into the database. I pass a msg just to let the user know if everything went okay or if some problem appear (like for instnace, if the user gave wrong information). Hope that helps to understand..

Comment: I put the variable msg in some pieces of the code, to know wish msg he returned but it's empty, so I'm guessing it's something wrong with the way I handle the function. Because it redirects me to the other page

Comment: I don't think there is any problem with how you handle the function as such. I tried your code (removed the model related code snippet with some pseudo list and conditions) and it is working just fine. Even I am confused now :P

Comment: sorry I finally was able to get what was wrong.. I'm going to answer more in detail. Hope you understand my silly mistake

Comment: @pavid - please don't mention... we all are here to learn :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to understand my mistake.
sorry guys for my silly mistake

so this is the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url upload_done 'clinical' %}" method="post">
<div>
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %} 
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
</form>
```

urls:

```
url(r'^insert/file/(?P<word>clinical)/upload/$', last_step, name="upload"),
url(r'^insert/file/(?P<word>clinical)/upload/result/$', final, name='upload_done'),
```

so the view last_step corresponds to the url "upload" and not "upload_done"
I wrote into the form action={% url upload_done 'clinical' %}, so when I hit save it will redirect me automatically to the other template. Without running the code!!

So I changed the form to:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url upload 'clinical' %}" method="post">
<div>
    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %} 
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
</div>
</form>
```

and now it works..

sorry guys, I thought I needed to redirect to the other page but when he redirects he doesn't run the code..